# Sort array of ints based on another array of ints

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Suppose I have two arrays, like this:

```
var SortedArray = [25, 123, 2464, 112, 54, 51, 347, 4572, 634];
var ArrayToSort = [634, 25, 51, 123];
```

`SortedArray` is an array that contains the order of many elements. `ArrayToSort` contains just some of the elements of `SortedArray` and every element in `ArrayToSort` is certain to also be in `SortedArray`.

What's the best way to sort ArrayToSort so that the elements in that array appear in the same order as SortedArray and get this result:

```
ArrayToSort = [25, 123, 51, 634];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayToSort.sort(function(x, y) {
    return SortedArray.indexOf(x) - SortedArray.indexOf(y);
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/gDd6h/)

Note: using this method, if an element does not appear in `SortedArray`, it will be placed before all other elements that are found in `SortedArray`.

Comment: Wow, all this in one line!! Nice answer!

Answer (score 4):

You could do this as an alternative to sorting as you already have a sorted array of elements.

```
var sortedArray = [25, 123, 2464, 112, 54, 51, 347, 4572, 634],
    arrayToSort = [634, 25, 51, 123],
    sorted = sortedArray.filter(function (num) {
        return arrayToSort.indexOf(num) !== -1;
    });

console.log(sorted);
```

Output

```
[25, 123, 51, 634]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u775W/)

Comment: +1 I was about to add something like this as an alternative when your answer popped up.